# Is the sequence $\{(-1)^n 1/n\}$ divergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Is the sequence $\{(-1)^n{1\over n}\}$ divergent or convergent?

It's convergent to $0$ because for every $\varepsilon$, exists $1/N < \varepsilon$ by archimedean property, so $|1/n|< \varepsilon$ for all $n>N$?

Comment: This should be easy to answer if you try plotting this sequence in the plane.

Comment: It's convergent to 0 because for every ε, exists 1/N < ε by archimedean property, so |1/n|< ε for all n>N ?

Comment: @Ashley yes, and it converges to $0$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** $-1\le(-1)^n\le1$. Either that, or split it up into two subsequences, depending on the parity of *n*, and prove that both converge to the same limit.

Answer (score -3):

The sequence converges by the alternating series test.
$$ (-1)^n \over n $$
See a tutorial about alternating series test
http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/AlternatingSeries.aspx

This fits the criteria for convergence by the alternating series test.

Comment: The question is not about series.

Comment: Maybe user meant that, since the series is convergent then general term $\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$ converges to zero.